# General java override clone method

Tags: java, overriding, clone

Lets say I have super class A with clone able interface and deep overridden clone method.

I also have a subclass B.

```
B Temp = new B();
B Temp_Clone = (B) Temp.clone();
```

The method Temp.clone() returns a reference to the cloned super class A, right?

From my understanding, I can't put a reference to a super class in a sub class object, right?

So how is the code I written here is possible? because of the casting?

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you remove the casting to see if the compiler returns an error or not to find out about your last question? anyway I suppose if you do so, you will get a compile error; casting is needed when referencing a super-object by a sub-object reference variable. and look at @EJP answer in below, which I think is the best answer to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

> The class Object's clone() method creates and returns a copy of the
>   object, with the same class and with all the fields having the same
>   values. However, Object.clone() throws a CloneNotSupportedException
>   unless the object is an instance of a class that implements the marker
>   interface Cloneable.

Answer (score 0):

> The method Temp.clone() returns a reference to the cloned super class A, right?

Right.

> From my understanding, I can't put a reference to a super class in a sub class object, right?

Wrong.

> So how is the code I written here is possible? because of the casting?

I don't know what you think is impossible about it, but the casting is certainly required.

Comment: Well, because B Temp_Clone is a sub class, on the other hand, Temp.clone() is a super class, how can you reference a super class to a sub class object?

Comment: @user2102697 `A.clone()` returns a clone of the current object, whatever its type, which must be or extend A by definition, but it is *typed* as being of class Object, again by definition, so the typecast is necessary. This all follows directly from the method signature and its specification in the Javadoc.

Comment: @onepotato The OP has stated that A is a superclass of B.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if the code in A called super.clone so the object that created when you call Temp.clone is object from the type B. since clone does not call constructor! clone method implemented in the object class as native class and preform member wise copy and create the same object as the this object. so ClonedTemp is from B type.